# Android: pass value to view after setContentView

Tags: android

New to Android and having some trouble passing data from an activity to a view. I have a simple Android onCreate method for my Activity.

```
public class MyActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        int num = intent.getIntExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_NUM, 0);
        setContentView(R.layout.play_game); //this is a MyView class inside of a LinearLayout
        //where I want to pass the value of num to MyView
        MyView myView = (MyView) findViewById(R.id.myview);
        myView.setNum(num);
    }
}


public class MyView extends View {
    protected int num;
    protected int[] array;

    public MyView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet) {
        super(context, attributeSet);
        init();
    }

    protected void init() {
        setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pic1);
        array = new int[num];
    }

    public void setNum(int num) {
        this.num = num;
    }
}
```

However, I can't figure out how to pass a value to the MyView class (it extends View). I just want to send an integer value that the view class will get before starting the constructor.

Comment: where is the MyView class?

Comment: If you don't want to add a setter to your view, you can get that value from the intent directly from your view. In your custom view, use `int num = ((Activity)context).getIntent().getIntExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_NUM, 0);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Add a `setter` method to yours `MyView` class

   ```
   public void setNum(int num)
   {
       this.num=num;
   }
   ```
2. In `MyActivity` find yours view

   ```
   MyView myView=(MyView) findViewById(R.id.ID_OF_YOURS_VIEW_IN_ACTIVITYS_LAYOUT);
   ```
3. Set yours value to yours view by passing it to `setter` method

   ```
   myView.setNum(num);
   ```

Comment: so I updated my code above (the xml was already there) to what I tried. However, it looks like the view is attempting to initialize before I get to set the number. Therefore it calls init without the num value set and is failing. Thoughts?

Comment: You can set a default value to MyView.num field. This will prevent crushing. Then, you must call `init()` after setting value. You can call it inside setNum();

Answer (score 1):

Get your view id by `findViewById()` in `oncreate()` of MyActivity class

```
MyView mv=(MyView) findViewById(R.id.your-view-id);
```

Then set the value by a method `getdata()`

```
mv.getdata(value);
```

where `getdata()` method looks like

```
public void getdata(int value)
{
  this.value=value;
}
```

Comment: But I'd like to keep the View from not knowing about the Activity. Isn't there a way to pass data to a view just like how Intents are used to pass data from one activity to another? I'd much prefer that way instead of having the View need to communicate back with the activity.

Comment: You never create a new activity from a view.

Comment: Just missed the point that MyView was extending view class and made a mistake. However it is corrected now. Thanks @sbaar

Answer (score 0):

after setContentView

```
MyView mv = (MyView) findviewById(R.id.myView);
mv.setData(int number);
```

You'll need to make setData public. Make sure you set the id of myview with

```
 android:id="@+id/myView"
```

in xml.

Comment: so I updated my code above (the xml was already there) to what I tried. However, it looks like the view is attempting to initialize before I get to set the number. Therefore it calls init without the num value set and is failing. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You have several options :

Remove initialization of the array from init() or give it a default value for avoiding error as others suggested. It depends whether an array with a default value makes sense or not in your context. Finally inject the number with a setter.

You can also define a static method for setting the number from the activity before the view constructor get called (do it before inflating view with findViewById()).  But generatly it is a bad practice and should be used in specific cases.

The real question may be : does the init() call makes sense in constructors and  the array must be set at view construction?  Can't it be initialized afterward?